# New Inspiron laptop won't open disc tray

Tags: windows-8, laptop, vmware, dell-inspiron

My new Inspiron 17R laptop from Dell pre-installed with Windows 8 won't open it's disk tray. This only happens after using VMWare Player and an OS install disk. For example, just now, I booted a VM in VMWare Player off of an Arch Linux 2013 install disk, and after I finished, it would only open by the old paperclip trick.

EDIT:
Restarting seems to get rid of the problem.

Comment: When you were trying to open the CD drive was the VM turned off?

Comment: Pressing the button on the drive doesn't open it, it sends a message to the OS saying the button was pressed.  Then the OS tells the drive to open.  It's not clear what your scenario is, but I'm guessing the message isn't getting back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

Linux will not allow your CD drive to open if a CD is in there and it has been mounted in the OS. Have you tried unmounting the device and are you shutting down the VM or are you "suspending" it?

**EDIT:**

**NOTE:** You can use the following command in a shell/terminal window to "unmount" the CD drive:

```
% sudo umount /dev/cdrom
```

After that you should be able to eject the drive.

Comment: Perhaps you could add to your answer methods that the OP could use to unmount?

Comment: @slm - While I suppose that is the real answer, its not clear the user is using Linux, since he only mentions using Windows 8.  The virtual machine wouldn't have blocked the drive from opening if it wasn't running.

Comment: @Ramhound OP mentions the problem only occurs after running VMWare with Arch linux hence me assuming the problem is Linux related.